# Is it possible to create a Mouse Hover state for a WPF element that is not a button?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mouseevent

I have a bunch of buttons with `Trigger`s and hover effects. I found some problems overriding my theme, so I was wondering if I can add Mouse Hover effects to other elements, such as `TextBlock`s or `StackPanel`s. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible but Limited, But setting background is the only siple option

```
  <TextBlock Text="Hello World!" Margin="0,23,0,111">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property= "Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                       <Trigger Property ="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property= "Background" >
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                        <GradientStopCollection>
                                            <GradientStop Color="Aqua" Offset="0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1" />
                                        </GradientStopCollection>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                       </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
```

Result

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks! Yours has a nicer gradient anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Just found out it IS possible. Leaving it as answer just in case.

Hover State for a `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock Text="Textblock">   
        <TextBlock.Style>    
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">      
                <Style.Triggers>         
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">     
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Blue" />   
                    </Trigger>    
                </Style.Triggers>     
            </Style>   
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
```